# WCF how to avoid defining many operationcontracts

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

In my interface, I will have many functions. All of these will be binded as OperationContract.

Is there a way to avoid typing [OperationContract] on every single one of these functions?

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IStudentService
{
    [OperationContract]
    String GetStudentFullName (int studentId);

    [OperationContract]
    StudentInformation GetStudentInfo (int studentId);
    ... about 20 more
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should avoid service contracts, containing big number (like 20 or more) of operation contracts.

First you can do, is to change pattern, which your service is build on. Instead of posting and returning single data value as a result of operation, use DTOs (or STE, if this is applicable for you) and operate on object graph:

```
[OperationContract]
StudentDTO GetStudent(int studentId);
[OperationContract]
StudentDTO UpdateStudent(CreateStudentDTO student);
[OperationContract]
StudentDTO UpdateStudent(UpdateStudentDTO student);

[DataContract]
public class StudentDTO
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public StudentInformationDTO StudentInformation { get; set; }

  // other student's data here
}
```

The second thing - break such contracts into small ones (remember single responsibility principle). You shouldn't do contracts, which are responsible for all over the world.

Comment: Good answer... couldn't have put it better myself

Answer (score 1):

No easy way of doing this. All methods must be decorated with the [OperationContract] attribute if you want them to be available to clients of the service.

Answer (score 1):

For client visibility, all methods must be decorated with [OperationContract].  It looks like you're building a chatty interface (GetStudentThis(id), GetStudentThat(id), etc.) - very much like stored procedures.  Try to make your interface chunky by having fewer methods that do more work.

For example, pass-in a "request" object to all your methods.  This request will encapsulate the parameters needed to execute your method.  Something like this:  GetStudent(StudentRequestObject/Message request).  Now, your method implementation can examine the contents of the single parameter, act accordingly, and return a "response" object to the client encapsulating the payload.

The result will be less methods ([OperationContract]), easier maintenance, and less code.